# Does 同棲 always have a romantic connotation?

Tags: meaning, nuances, nouns, connotation

Take for instance the noun,

`同棲組` which roughly means a `group living together`.

Does `同棲` *always* have a romantic connotation, or is it possible to use it in a non-romantic sense.  For example, to describe a group of friends living together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the main contemporary usage is for non-married people with a romantic affiliation to be 'shacking up' together, this is not 100% definitive (see the [Wikipedia page](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%90%8C%E6%A3%B2)).

Other words exist (一緒に住む、同居) to indicate simple cohabitation, so for all intents and purposes, a romantic link would be implied ([Weblio page](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/cohabitation)).

Comment: In modern Japanese 同棲 *almost always* has a romantic connotation, but it is true that 同棲 *was* used like 同居 without romantic implication in the old days. In Aozora Bunko (library of old public-domain literary works), we can find examples like 「母と妹とは自分達夫婦と同棲するのが窮屈で」, 「一船は一家にして、父子同棲するも」 and 「妻子と同棲することには父の頑強な反対があった」.

Answer (score 7):

> Does 同棲 always have a romantic connotation, or is it possible to use it in a non-romantic sense.

I think it always has a romantic connotation... I've never heard it used in a non-romantic sense.

> 同棲組 which roughly means a group living together.

I think it's used to refer to "(the kind/group/category of) people who are living with their partner / choose to live with their partner rather than getting married".

> For example, to describe a group of friends living together?

I don't think we use 同棲 to describe that...